# ALB Trigger Lamda function missing permission CDK

Tags: aws-lambda, permissions, aws-cdk

Currently i've got a problem to invoke a Lamda function from an ALB as a trigger function. I am getting the error massage , that

```
elasticloadbalancing principal does not have permission to 
invoke arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:ACN:function  
API: elasticloadbalancingv2:RegisterTargets elasticloadbalancing principal
does not have permission to invoke arn:aws:lambda:us-east-...function:Ddns
from target group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:...targetgroup/DdnsL
```

```
export class DdnsLamdaApiGateWayCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'global-vpc', {
      vpcId: 'vpc-a0b8bec8',
    });

    const sg = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'SG', 'sg-0740900526b94fd8f')

    const fn = new lambda.Function(this, "API", {
      handler: 'index.handler',
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      role: Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'lambda-role', 'arn:aws:iam::.....:role/service-role/LamdaR'),
      code: Code.fromInline("test"),

    });

    fn.addToRolePolicy( new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      resources: [
        "*"
      ]

    }));

    const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "LoadBalancer", {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: false,
      securityGroup: sg
    });

    const listener = lb.addListener("Listener", {
      port: 80,
    });

    listener.addTargets('Targets', {
      targets: [new LambdaALBTarget(fn)]
    });
  }
}

class LambdaALBTarget implements elbv2.IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget {
  private fn: lambda.IFunction;

  constructor(fn: lambda.IFunction) {
    this.fn = fn;
  }

  attachToApplicationTargetGroup(
      targetGroup: elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup
  ): elbv2.LoadBalancerTargetProps {
    return {
      targetType: "lambda" as elbv2.TargetType,
      targetJson: {
        id: this.fn.functionArn
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I am assuming -> that I missing this particular Permission:

```
LambdaFunctionPermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaTargetFunction.Arn
    Principal: elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !Ref TargetGroup
```

But I cannot figure out know how to include this Permision in the given source-code. Does anyone had the same issue and know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked the generated IAM role for the Lambda? Does that permission figure in it?

Comment: well I've checked the template.json file:

regarding the I AM role :
 "lambdarolePolicy2FC0B982": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "PolicyName": "lambdarolePolicy2FC0B982",
        "Roles": [
          "LamdaR"
        ]
      },

I am allowing every resource to invoke the function.

Comment: It seems like, that my target group does not have the permission to call the lamda function , how can I add those permission ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a workaround where the permission is set automatically when deploying the stack instead of creating the class LambdaALBTarget and then call the method attachToApplicationTargetGroup, just add the (new LambdaTarget) to the listener -> attachToApplicationTargetGroup&attachToNetworkTargetGroup get automatically called when you add the target to a load balancer

```
listener.addTargets('Targets', {
      targets: [new LambdaTarget(fn)]
    });
...
```

here the section of created invoke function permission (template.json)

```
"APIInvokeServicePrincipalelasticloadbalancingamazonawscom68C82386": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "API62EA1CFF",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Principal": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "DdnsLamdaApiGateWayCdkStack/API/InvokeServicePrincipal(elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com)"
      }
```

Here is the finished Source-Code

```
export class DdnsLamdaApiGateWayCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'global-vpc', {
      vpcId: '....',
    });

    const code = fs.readFileSync('./code.js','utf8');


    const dnsRegistrationRole = new Role(this, 'DnsRegRole', {
        roleName: 'Lamda-DnsRegRole',
        managedPolicies: [
            ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonVPCFullAccess'),
            ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonRoute53AutoNamingRegistrantAccess'),
            ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole '),
        ],
        inlinePolicies: {
            Route53ListHostedZone: new PolicyDocument({
                statements: [
                    new PolicyStatement({
                        actions: ['route53:ListResourceRecordSets'],
                        resources: ['arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*'],
                    }),
                ],
            }),
        },
        assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
    });

      const dnsRegistrationLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "API", {
          handler: 'index.handler',
          runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
          role: dnsRegistrationRole,
          code: Code.fromInline(code),
          memorySize: 256,

      });

      const loadBalancerSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, "loadBalancer-security-group", {
      vpc: vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
      description: 'loadBalancerSecurityGroup'
      });

    loadBalancerSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),ec2.Port.tcp(80),"HTTP");
    loadBalancerSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),ec2.Port.tcp(443),"HTTPS")


    const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "LoadBalancer", {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: true,
      securityGroup: loadBalancerSecurityGroup
    });

    const listener = lb.addListener("Listener", {
      port: 80,
    });

    listener.addTargets('Targets', {
      targets: [new LambdaTarget(dnsRegistrationLambda)]
    });
  }
}
```

basically i've build a serverless Dynamic DNS System with ALB&Lamda